# Why can we join on a nonconstraint?

Tags: sql

I'm working with a database with poor design. Most tables do have a PK, but FK's do not exist.  This makes it difficult to visualize the relationships between the tables.  This leads me to wonder, why does SQL let us join tables with no constraint?  If I am going to join Table A on Table B with EmployeeId shouldn't the knee jerk reaction be to setup a FK?

Comment: The knee jerk reaction of a _skilled developer_, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because constraints are *optional*.

I agree that not using constraints is usually a bad idea, but in general, one doesn't *have* to have constraints for a valid database design to be created.

Some applications require that no constraints are used say for a hard delete of a "current" record that still has an audit trail table (which some reports will join on).

In such a scenario, not being able to join would hamper flexibility and the ability to use the DB.

This of course leave aside the fact that many databases are created by people (business or developers) that don't know about or care about referential integrity.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - Just think about the flexibility you would lose if you did enforce such a rule.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases u might join on dates etc where u dont want to set up Fk or it might be impossible. Its ur decision if u want to define fk or not

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy of SQL is that the person writing the query just needs to know the tables and columns; they don't need to know any of the indexes or table relationships.  The database is supposed to be smart enough to figure out how to perform the query efficiently.

For ad-hoc queries this is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key affects performance since each time you insert a record it needs to ensure that the constraint is not being violated. In high-performance systems, database would often have FK in development and QA environment but not in production to speed up the inserts. The difference in performance can be huge if a lot of inserts are being performed and the database tables are large.

This is only one of many reasons SQL allows you to join without constraints.

Comment: You'd most likely still have an FK in production to *protect your data*. If you have billion row tables then you'd evaluate case by case with careful deliberation: but that's not what you'd do at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You may not join directly related tables

- Numbers table
- Cross joins
- table to grandparent, bypassing parent table
- ...

Answer (score 0):

GASP!  You can even join on *nothing!*